# What are these diagrams called? And, what are some good *free* books/notes where I can learn about them?

Tags: logic, reference-request, terminology

I ran into the following diagrams while randomly browsing internet

[image: Valid XHTML]

[image: Valid XHTML]

I'd like to learn about them.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic ?

Answer (score 1):

The diagrams you posted are ways of representing formal deductions/proof in formal systems (also called proof systems or logical calculi).

As an example you can take a look to wikipedia's page on [sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus).

You can find more about this on any book on mathematical logic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The diagrams are examples of an argument that has been formalized using Boolean logic. The different symbols represent different quantifiers such as (and, or, if,).

You can learn more for free at wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

A cheap but good book on the subject is: Boolean Reasoning by Brown.

[http://www.amazon.com/Boolean-Reasoning-Logic-Equations-Mathematics/dp/0486427854/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451854924&sr=8-1&keywords=boolean+logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486427854)

Answer (score 0):

The examples in your question are some of the rules of inference in a *natural deduction* system.  (This is very similar to a sequent calculus but not quite the same.)